# How to set property asynchronously using useEffect for later use in function within a React component?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

So here is the scenario, I have a property which I need to initialize using `useEffect`. The problem is, this property is also used within a function within my component.

So I have a situation, where the property shows up as undefined when the function is later called in the component, this is because by the time the function is being initialized, the asyncronous call that sets it in `useEffect` has not being finished yet.

```
  let myprop;

  useEffect(() => {
    const setUp = async (): Promise<void> => {
      myprop = initFuncThatReturnsAPromise;
    };

    void setUp();
  });

  const process = () => {
   // uses myprop for example
   myprop.call()
  }
```

`process` function is attached to a click event later on in the component. Problem now is, when the click event is clicked and process is executed, `myprop` is undefined. That is because it takes a while for the async function in `useEffect` to resolve and sets its value.

Any ideas on how to go around this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the function conditionally, so that it is only called once the function exists:

```
const process = () => {
   // uses myprop for example
   myprop && myprop.call()
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work. The myprop is always undefefined.